# Getting VertexRenderingFunction to (not) scale

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm having problem with custom VertexRenderingFunction showing at different sizes for different graphs. An example is below, the default vertex rendering function has the desired behavior since vertices look the same in all graphs, any suggestion how to achieve that with custom vertices?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/vrf-scaling.png))</sub>

```
edges = Most[
    ArrayRules[GraphData[{"Path", 5}, "AdjacencyMatrix"]]][[All, 1]];
doit[vrf_] := 
  Print /@ Table[
    GraphPlot[Rule @@@ edges[[k ;;]], VertexRenderingFunction -> vrf, 
     VertexLabeling -> True], {k, 1, Length[edges]}];
doit[({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)];
doit[Automatic];
```

**Update, 1 hour later**:

Michael Pilat as usual gives the solution, here's what it looks like with

```
(Inset[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, .05], Black, 
     Text[#2, {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 25], #] &)
```

for rendering function

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/vrf-scaling-fixed.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html) a `Graphics` expression with the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) option to place your vertices:

```
GraphPlot[Rule @@@ edges,
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
     Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, .05], Black, 
       Text[#2, {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 25], #] &),
 VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`ImageSize` can take a variety of values from printer's points to a [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scaled.html) value.

`Inset` can also/instead take a size in its fourth argument, but the default setting defers to the `ImageSize` of the inset `Graphics` object, which is a little cleaner to use in this case.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice! Thanks for that solution, I was having the same problem a while back.