# Consistent size for GraphPlots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

**Update 10/27**: I've put detailed steps for achieving consistent scale in an answer. Basically for each Graphics object you need to fix all padding/margins to 0 and manually specify plotRange and imageSize that such that 1) plotRange includes all graphics 2) imageSize=scale*plotRange

Still now sure how to do 1) in full generality, a solution that works for Graphics consisting of points and thick lines (AbsoluteThickness) is given

---

I'm using "Inset" in VertexRenderingFunction and "VertexCoordinates" to guarantee consistent appearance among subgraphs of a graph. Those subgraphs are drawn as vertices of another graph, using "Inset". There are two problems, one is that resulting boxes are not cropped around the graph (ie, graph with one vertex still gets placed in a big box), and another is that there's strange variation among sizes (you can see one box is vertical). Can anyone see a way around these problems?

This is related to an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121523/getting-vertexrenderingfunction-to-not-scale) of how to keep vertex sizes looking the same, and while Michael Pilat's suggestion of using Inset works to keep vertices rendering at the same scale, overall scale may be different. For instance on the left branch, the graph consisting of vertices 2,3 is stretched relative to the "2,3" subgraph in the top graph, even though I'm using absolute vertex positioning for both

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/bad-graph.png))</sub>

```
(*utilities*)intersect[a_, b_] := Select[a, MemberQ[b, #] &];
induced[s_] := Select[edges, #~intersect~s == # &];
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
subgraphs[
   verts_] := (gr = 
    Rule @@@ Select[edges, (Intersection[#, verts] == #) &];
   Sort /@ WeakComponents[gr~Join~(# -> # & /@ verts)]);

(*graph*)
gname = {"Grid", {3, 3}};
edges = GraphData[gname, "EdgeIndices"];
nodes = Union[Flatten[edges]];
AppendTo[edges, #] & /@ ({#, #} & /@ nodes);
vcoords = Thread[nodes -> GraphData[gname, "VertexCoordinates"]];

(*decompose*)
edgesOuter = {};
pr[_, _, {}] := None;
pr[root_, elim_, 
   remain_] := (If[root != {}, AppendTo[edgesOuter, root -> remain]];
   pr[remain, intersect[Rest[elim], #], #] & /@ 
    subgraphs[Complement[remain, {First[elim]}]];);
pr[{}, {4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 2, 3, 7, 9}, nodes];

(*visualize*)

vrfInner = 
  Inset[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, .05], Black, 
      Text[#2, {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 15], #] &;
vrfOuter = 
  Inset[GraphPlot[Rule @@@ induced[#2], 
     VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfInner, 
     VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords, SelfLoopStyle -> None, 
     Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 100], #] &;
TreePlot[edgesOuter, Automatic, nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, Arrow[#1, 0.2]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfOuter, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Here's another example, same problem as before, but the difference in relative scales is more visible. The goal is to have parts in the second picture match precisely the parts in the first picture.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/bad-plot2.png))</sub>

```
(* Visualize tree decomposition of a 3x3 grid *)

inducedGraph[set_] := Select[edges, # \[Subset] set &];
Subset[a_, b_] := (a \[Intersection] b == a);
graphName = {"Grid", {3, 3}};
edges = GraphData[graphName, "EdgeIndices"];
vars = Range[GraphData[graphName, "VertexCount"]];
vcoords = Thread[vars -> GraphData[graphName, "VertexCoordinates"]];

plotHighlight[verts_, color_] := Module[{vpos, coords},
   vpos = 
    Position[Range[GraphData[graphName, "VertexCount"]], 
     Alternatives @@ verts];
   coords = Extract[GraphData[graphName, "VertexCoordinates"], vpos];
   If[coords != {}, AppendTo[coords, First[coords] + .002]];
   Graphics[{color, CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"], 
     Thickness[.2], Opacity[.3], Line[coords]}]];

jedges = {{{1, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}, {{2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}, {{4, 
     5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 8}}, {{4, 7, 8}, {4, 
     5, 6, 8}}, {{6, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 6, 8}}};
jnodes = Union[Flatten[jedges, 1]];

SeedRandom[1]; colors = 
 RandomChoice[ColorData["WebSafe", "ColorList"], Length[jnodes]];
bags = MapIndexed[plotHighlight[#, bc[#] = colors[[First[#2]]]] &, 
   jnodes];
Show[bags~
  Join~{GraphPlot[Rule @@@ edges, VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords, 
    VertexLabeling -> True]}, ImageSize -> Small]

bagCentroid[bag_] := Mean[bag /. vcoords];
findExtremeBag[vec_] := (
   vertList = First /@ vcoords;
   coordList = Last /@ vcoords;
   extremePos = 
    First[Ordering[jnodes, 1, 
      bagCentroid[#1].vec > bagCentroid[#2].vec &]];
   jnodes[[extremePos]]
   );

extremeDirs = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}};
extremeBags = findExtremeBag /@ extremeDirs;
extremePoses = bagCentroid /@ extremeBags;
vrfOuter = 
  Inset[Show[plotHighlight[#2, bc[#2]], 
     GraphPlot[Rule @@@ inducedGraph[#2], 
      VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords, SelfLoopStyle -> None, 
      VertexLabeling -> True], ImageSize -> 100], #] &;

GraphPlot[Rule @@@ jedges, VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfOuter, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, Arrowheads[0], Arrow[#1, 0]} &), 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 VertexCoordinateRules -> Thread[Thread[extremeBags -> extremePoses]]]
```

Any other suggestions for aesthetically pleasing visualization of graph operations are welcome.

Comment: I never  achieved a consistent image sizing, not only with graphs, but also when superimposing images and plots. Hope someone holds the magic wand and lend it to us ...

Comment: You are getting some really nice looking graphs happening. When you've finished this project you're working on are you going to release a package for the rest of us plebs?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you write your own version of `Intersection`?

Comment: Sure, working on implementation of "Generalized Distributive Law" and I'll make it available as soon as it's not embarrassing. Used `intersection` because `Intersection` sorts list

Comment: Added to toolbag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps needed to achieve precise control over relative scales of graphics objects.

To achieve consistent scale one needs to explicitly specify input coordinate range (regular coordinates) and output coordinate range (absolute coordinates). Regular coordinate range depends on `PlotRange`, `PlotRangePadding` (and possibly others options?). Absolute coordinate range depends on `ImageSize`,`ImagePadding` (and possibly other options?). For `GraphPlot`, it is sufficient to specify `PlotRange` and `ImageSize`.

To create Graphics object that renders at a pre-determined scale, you need to figure out `PlotRange` needed to fully include the object, corresponding `ImageSize` and return `Graphics` object with these settings specified. To figure out the necessary `PlotRange` when thick lines are involved it is easier to deal with `AbsoluteThickness`, call it `abs`. To fully include those lines you could take the smallest `PlotRange` that includes endpoints, then offset minimum x and maximum y boundaries by abs/2, and offset maximum x and minimum y boundaries by (abs/2+1). Note that these are output coordinates.

When combining several `scale-calibrated` Graphics objects you need to recalculate `PlotRange/ImageSize` and set them explicitly for the combined Graphics object.

To Inset `scale-calibrated` objects into `GraphPlot` you need to make sure that coordinates used for automatic `GraphPlot` positioning are in the same range. For that, you could pick several corner nodes, fix their positions manually, and let automatic positioning do the rest.

Primitives `Line`/`JoinedCurve`/`FilledCurve` render joins/caps differently depending on whether the line is (almost) collinear, so one needs to manually detect collinearity.

Using this approach, rendered images should have width equal to

`(inputPlotRange*scale + 1) + lineThickness*scale + 1`

First extra `1` is to avoid the "fencepost error" and second extra 1 is the extra pixel needed to add on the right to make sure thick lines are not cut-off

I've verified this formula by doing `Rasterize` on combined `Show` and rasterizing a 3D plot with objects mapped using `Texture` and viewed with `Orthographic` projection and it matches the predicted result. Doing 'Copy/Paste' on objects `Inset` into `GraphPlot`, and then Rasterizing, I get an image that's one pixel thinner than predicted.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/graphPlots.png))</sub>

```
(**** Note, this uses JoinedCurve and Texture which are Mathematica 8 primitives.
      In Mathematica 7, JoinedCurve is not needed and can be removed *)

(** Global variables **)
scale = 50;
lineThickness = 1/2; (* line thickness in regular coordinates *)

(** Global utilities **)

(* test if 3 points are collinear, needed to work around difference \
in how colinear Line endpoints are rendered *)

collinear[points_] := 
 Length[points] == 3 && (Det[Transpose[points]~Append~{1, 1, 1}] == 0)

(* tales list of point coordinates, returns plotRange bounding box, \
uses global "scale" and "lineThickness" to get bounding box *)

getPlotRange[lst_] := (
   {xs, ys} = Transpose[lst];
   (* two extra 1/
   scale offsets needed for exact match *)
   {{Min[xs] - 
      lineThickness/2, 
     Max[xs] + lineThickness/2 + 1/scale}, {Min[ys] - 
      lineThickness/2 - 1/scale, Max[ys] + lineThickness/2}}
   );

(* Gets image size for given plot range *)

getImageSize[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}] := (
   imsize = scale*{xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin} + {1, 1}
   );

(* converts plot range to vertices of rectangle *)

pr2verts[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}] := {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, 
    ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}};

(* lifts two dimensional coordinates into 3d *)

lift[h_, coords_] := Append[#, h] & /@ coords
(* convert Raster object to array specification of texture *)

raster2texture[raster_] := Reverse[raster[[1, 1]]/255]

Subset[a_, b_] := (a \[Intersection] b == a);
inducedGraph[set_] := Select[edges, # \[Subset] set &];
values[dict_] := Map[#[[-1]] &, DownValues[dict]];


(** Graph Specific Stuff *)
graphName = {"Grid", {3, 3}};
verts = Range[GraphData[graphName, "VertexCount"]];
edges = GraphData[graphName, "EdgeIndices"];
vcoords = Thread[verts -> GraphData[graphName, "VertexCoordinates"]];
jedges = {{{1, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}, {{2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}, {{4, 
     5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 8}}, {{4, 7, 8}, {4, 
     5, 6, 8}}, {{6, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 6, 8}}};
jnodes = Union[Flatten[jedges, 1]];


(* Generate diagram with explicit PlotRange,ImageSize and \
AbsoluteThickness *)
plotHL[verts_, color_] := (
   coords = verts /. vcoords;
   obj = JoinedCurve[Line[coords], 
     CurveClosed -> Not[collinear[coords]]];

   (* Figure out PlotRange and ImageSize needed to respect scale *)

    pr = getPlotRange[verts /. vcoords];
   {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = pr;
   imsize = scale*{xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin};
   lineForm = {Opacity[.3], color, JoinForm["Round"], 
     CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[scale*lineThickness]};
   g = Graphics[{Directive[lineForm], obj}];
   gg = GraphPlot[Rule @@@ inducedGraph[verts], 
     VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords];
   Show[g, gg, PlotRange -> pr, ImageSize -> imsize]
   );

(* Initialize all graph plot images *)
SeedRandom[1]; colors = 
 RandomChoice[ColorData["WebSafe", "ColorList"], Length[jnodes]];
Clear[bags];
MapThread[(bags[#1] = plotHL[#1, #2]) &, {jnodes, colors}];

(** Ploting parent graph of subgraphs **)

(* figure out coordinates of subgraphs close to edges of bounding \
box, use them to anchor parent GraphPlot *)

bagCentroid[bag_] := Mean[bag /. vcoords];
findExtremeBag[vec_] := (vertList = First /@ vcoords;
   coordList = Last /@ vcoords;
   extremePos = 
    First[Ordering[jnodes, 1, 
      bagCentroid[#1].vec > bagCentroid[#2].vec &]];
   jnodes[[extremePos]]);

extremeDirs = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}};
extremeBags = findExtremeBag /@ extremeDirs;
extremePoses = bagCentroid /@ extremeBags;

(* figure out new plot range needed to contain all objects *)

fullPR = getPlotRange[verts /. vcoords];
fullIS = getImageSize[fullPR];

(*** Show bags together merged ***)
image1 = 
 Show[values[bags], PlotRange -> fullPR, ImageSize -> fullIS]

(*** Show bags as vertices of another GraphPlot ***)
GraphPlot[
 Rule @@@ jedges,
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Gray, Thick, Arrowheads[.05], 
     Arrow[#1, 0.22]} &),
 VertexCoordinateRules -> 
  Thread[Thread[extremeBags -> extremePoses]],
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[bags[#2], #] &),
 PlotRange -> fullPR,
 ImageSize -> 3*fullIS
 ]

(*** Show bags as 3d slides ***)
makeSlide[graphics_, pr_, h_] := (
  Graphics3D[{
    Texture[raster2texture[Rasterize[graphics, Background -> None]]],
    EdgeForm[None],
    Polygon[lift[h, pr2verts[pr]], 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> pr2verts[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
    }]
  )
yoffset = 1/2;
slides = MapIndexed[
   makeSlide[bags[#], getPlotRange[# /. vcoords], 
     yoffset*First[#2]] &, jnodes];
Show[slides, ImageSize -> 3*fullIS]

(*** Show 3d slides in orthographic projection ***)
image2 = 
 Show[slides, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, ImageSize -> fullIS, 
  Boxed -> False]

(*** Check that 3d and 2d images rasterize to identical resolution ***)
Dimensions[Rasterize[image1][[1, 1]]] == 
 Dimensions[Rasterize[image2][[1, 1]]]
```

Comment: +1 very nice ... I suggest to add a "Mathematica 8" warning in the code header. You could accept your answer without shame  :D

Answer (score 2):

OK, in your comment to my previous answer (this is a different approach), you said the problem was the interaction between GraphPlot/Inset/PlotRange. If you don't specify a size for `Inset`, then it inherits its size from the `ImageSize` of the inset `Graphics` object.

Here's my edit of the final section in you first example, this time taking into account the *size* of the `Inset` graphs.

```
(*visualize*)
vrfInner = Inset[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, .05], Black, 
      Text[#2, {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 15], #, Center] &;
vrfOuter = Module[{edges = Rule @@@ induced[#2], prange, psize},
    prange = Union /@ Transpose[Union[Flatten[List @@@ edges]] /. vcoords];
    prange = {Min[#] - .5, Max[#] + .5} & /@ prange;
    psize = Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ prange;
    Inset[GraphPlot[edges, VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfInner, 
       VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords, SelfLoopStyle -> None, 
       Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 100, PlotRange -> prange, 
       PlotRangePadding -> None], #, Center, Scaled[psize {.05, .04}],
       Background -> None ]] &;
TreePlot[edgesOuter, Automatic, nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, Arrow[#1, 0.25]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfOuter, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

n.b. the `{.05, .04}` would have to be modified as the size and layout of the outer graph changes...
To automate the whole thing, you might need a nice way for the inner and outer graphics objects to inspect each other...

Comment: Nice, looks like it works for this graph. I think inspecting inner/outer graphics would make it too complicated. The question is really -- how to render GraphPlots inside Inset inside VertexRenderingFunction at a given scale. IE, I want 10 pixels of GraphPlot's image to correspond to x units of logical distance, where x is a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your first example by changing *vrfOuter* as follows:

```
vrfOuter =
  Inset[
    Framed@GraphPlot[
      Rule@@@induced[#2],
      VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfInner,
      VertexCoordinateRules -> vcoords,
      SelfLoopStyle -> None,
      ImageSize -> {100, 100},
      AspectRatio -> 1,
      PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}
    ],
    #
  ] &;
```

I removed the *Frame->All* option and added a wrapping call to *Framed*.  This is because I find that I cannot adequately control the margins outside of the frame generated by the former.  I might be missing some option somewhere, but *Framed* works the way I want without fuss.

I added an explicit height to the *ImageSize* option.  Without it, Mathematica tries to choose a height using some algorithm that mostly produces pleasing results, but sometimes (as here) gets confused.

I added the *AspectRatio* option for the same reason -- Mathematica tries to choose a "pleasing" aspect ratio (typically the Golden Ratio), but we don't want that here.

I added the *PlotRange* option to ensure that each subgraph is using the same co-ordinate system.  Without it, Mathematica will usually select a minimal range that shows all nodes.

The results are shown below.  I leave it as an exercise to the reader to adjust the arrows, margins, etc. ;)

[image: rendered result]

*Edit*: added the *PlotRange* option in response to a comment by @Yaroslav Bulatov

Comment: It's better, but the scale is still not uniform, ie, part with "2,3" is rendered stretched in relation to top graph

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: I updated my answer to address your comment by adding the PlotRange option.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes "non-uniform scale" problem, although it adds a problem of wasted space (it was the other way round for the previous solution)

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack, you could introduce a ghost graph to force all subgraphs to display on the same grid.  Here's my modification of the last part of your first example -- my ghost graph is a copy of your original graph, but with the vertex numbers made negative.

```
(*visualize*)

ghost = GraphData[gname, "EdgeRules"] /. HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] :> -a -> -b;
vrfInner = If[#2 > 0, 
    Inset[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, .05], Black, 
       Text[#2, {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 15], #], {}] &;
erfInner = {If[TrueQ[#2[[1]] > 0], Blue, White], Line[#1]} &;
vrfOuter = Inset[GraphPlot[Join[Rule @@@ induced[#2], ghost],
     VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfInner, 
     VertexCoordinateRules -> (Join[#,#/.HoldPattern[a_->b_]:>-a -> b]&[vcoords]), 
     EdgeRenderingFunction -> erfInner, SelfLoopStyle -> None, 
     Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 100], #] &;
TreePlot[edgesOuter, Automatic, nodes, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Red, Arrow[#1, 0.2]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> vrfOuter, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

You could do the same thing for your second example.
Also, if you don't want the wasted vertical space you could write a quick function that checks which nodes are to be displayed and only keeps the ghosts on the needed rows.

**Edit:** The same output can be obtained by simply setting `PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {1, 3}}` for the inner graphs...

Comment: I thought I could get the same effect with "PlotRange->{0,4}" in vrfOuter, but the results are even stranger. The goal is to have 1) no wasted space and 2) consistent size. What you are proposing might work, I guess what I really want is an understanding of how GraphPlot/Inset/PlotRange work together