# How to determine PlotRange to include all of graphics?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given `Graphics` object, how do I determine the range of coordinates needed to include all of graphics? Basically I need something like what `Show` does by default, but I want to specify `PlotRange`,`PlotRangePadding` and `ImagePadding` explicitly.

Example, two `Show`s below should render the same

```
g = Graphics[{Thickness[1], CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}];
Show[g]
Show[g, PlotRange -> getPlotRange[g], PlotRangePadding->getPlotRangePadding[g], ImagePadding->getImagePadding[g]]
```

Motivation: fixing diagrams in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230823/consistent-size-for-graphplots) question

**Update**:
`AbsoluteOptions` gives me `PlotRange` but not the other two options. Explicitly specifying `ImagePadding->Automatic` changes appearance though it's supposedly `Automatic` by default.

Two images below show differently and I don't understand why

```
g = Graphics[{Thickness[1], CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}];
Show[g]
Show[g, Sequence @@ AbsoluteOptions[Show[g]]]
```

**Update 2**:
A similar problem was [brought up](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00144.html) a year ago, with no solutions proposed, and not fixed as of Mathematica 8.0. To summarize

1. There's no way to reproduce `Show[g]` above with explicit setting of `PlotRange`
2. There's no way to get absolute `ImagePadding` used by `Show[g]`
3. `Show[g,PlotRange->Automatic]` looks different from `Show[g]`
4. `AbsoluteOptions` can give the [wrong result](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00144.html) for `PlotRange`

Comment: I am playing with AbsoluteOptions too, but it returns wrong values sometimes

Comment: Yeah...maybe I'm better off implementing my own thick lines...

Comment: Seems the problem is not new http://thedailyreviewer.com/compsys/view/problems-absolute-plotrange-108108947

Comment: yup, that seems to be from MathGroup archive, and I get the same behavior as reported there in Mathematica 8

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest the following `Ticks` hack:

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
Reap[Rasterize[Show[pl, Ticks -> {Sow[{##}] &, Sow[{##}] &}, ImageSize -> 0], 
   ImageResolution -> 1]][[2, 1]]

=> {{-0.208333, 10.2083}, {-1.04167, 1.04167}}
```

The trick is that real `PlotRange` is determined by the FrontEnd, not by the Kernel. So we must force the FrontEnd to render the graphics in order to get tick functions evaluated. This hack gives the complete `PlotRange` with explicit value of `PlotRangePadding` added.

More general solution taking into account a possibility that `pl` has non-standard value of `DisplayFinction` option and that it may have `Axes` option set to `False`:

```
completePlotRange[plot:(_Graphics|_Graphics3D|_Graph)] := 
 Quiet@Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], ImageResolution -> 1]]
```

One can get the exact `PlotRange` (without the `PlotRangePadding` added) with the following function:

```
plotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
 Quiet@Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
       Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], 
      ImageResolution -> 1]]
```

---

P.S. On the Documentation page for `PlotRange` under the "More information" one can read: "`AbsoluteOptions` gives the actual settings for options used internally by *Mathematica* **when the setting given is `Automatic` or `All`**. " (emphasis mine). So it seems that the Documentation does not even guarantee that `AbsoluteOptions` will give correct values for `PlotRange` when it is not `Automatic` or `All`.

Comment: Sir, you are made of win! That last function is extremely useful.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, sometimes find it confusing how to get Mathematica to display `Graphics` in a consistent way, particularly when insetting graphics.

For the specified graphic `g`, it doesn't matter what you provide for the `PlotRange`, because `Thickness[1]` always draws a line whose thickness is equal to the horizontal plot range. In your example, `Show[g, ___]` gives the correct result:

[image: automatic image padding].

`Show[g]`, or simply `g`, is anomalous.

Why?

I don't know where/if this is documented, but here are a few things that might be relevant to the question.

1. Obviously `DisplayForm[Graphics[___]]` is a raster.
2. We can get a raster for g using Rasterize[g]. What is the RasterSize? From trial and 
   error, I found that RasterSize is 10 * screen resolution (reported as 72 pixels per inch on my system). How do I know this? If I rasterize g with resolutions less than 718, I get an image with dimensions {360,361}, whereas the default image size for g is 360 pixels on my system, so I figure to Show[] a graphic, Mathematica `Rasterize`'s it at 10x the screen resolution. Anybody know if this is true? You can get your screen resolution (at least as Mathematica sees it) from the Options Inspector.
   **Edit**
   That the following expression evaluates as `True` seems to show that the displayed graphic is rasterized at the ImageSize:
   `ImportString[ExportString[Show[g,ImageSize->100],"PNG"]]
   === ImportString[ExportString[Rasterize[g,RasterSize->100,ImageSize->100],"PNG"]`
3. To reproduce `Show[g]` when using `PlotRange` I need to use
   `Show[g,PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}},ImagePadding->90.3]`

[image: specific image padding]

to get it to crop to the perimeter of the line. So it seems that Mathematica is telling the truth that the `PlotRange` is `{{0,1},{0,1}}` when using `AbsoluteOptions[]`. It is not reporting the actual value of `ImagePadding`. Perhaps because `ImagePadding->Automatic` is based on a rule that uses the current `ImageSize`, `PlotRangeClipping`,... settings? The `ImagePadding` of 90.3 only works for `ImageSize->360`; setting `ImageSize->200` makes the `ImagePadding` value wrong. For your graphic, `ImagePadding->90.3*OptionValue[ImageSize]/360` reproduces `Show[g,ImageSize->_]` on my system.

That's all I've found out so far.

Comment: JxB Post the imgurl addresses of your images and I'll upload them.

Comment: @belisarius An upvote gave me enough rep to add the images. Thanks for the offer.

Comment: It may be that the analysis for part 2 of the list isn't right: The displayed raster might be rasterized at the image size...

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding a recognizable object at a known location and then see where it shows up in the exported version to provide a scale reference. I thought a vector export (SVG or EPS) would be easier to parse, but I think raster is easier after playing around a bit.

For example, add a green rectangle covering the theoretical plot range:

```
g = Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[1], CapForm["Round"], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}];
```

[image]

```
im = Rasterize[g, ImageSize -> 360];
xy = Transpose[Position[ImageData[im], {0., 1., 0.}]];
pad = Map[{Min[#1], 360 - Max[#1] } &, xy];
Show[g, ImagePadding -> pad]
```

The code is basically identifying where all the green pixels are.
The padding in this case is {{92, 92}, {92, 92}}, but it need not be symmetrical.