# Checking what choices Mathematica makes when you specify "Automatic"

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So I'm doing some benchmarking of a method for numerical optimization in Mathematica and I'm getting some inconsistent results when I use the Method->Automatic specification with FindMinimum. What I want to do is check what method it is choosing. I know I can use AbsoluteOptions[] to extract the choices from a some output, like a Graphics object, but this doesn't work with FindMinimum, ie

AbsoluteOptions[ Findminimum[ f[x], {x, 0.}, Method->Automatic ], Method ]

doesn't work. Can I do this?

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions` doesn't work like people wish it did.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288713/how-to-determine-plotrange-to-include-all-of-graphics as an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a general way to find what method is used by numerical functions, other than reading the documentation.  The documentation on [unconstrained optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroductionLocalMinimization.html) is pretty good, though.  There it says:

> With `Method -> Automatic`, Mathematica uses the "quasi-Newton" method 
>   unless the problem is structurally a sum of squares, in which case 
>   the Levenberg-Marquardt variant of the "Gauss-Newton" method is used. 
>   When given two starting conditions in each variable, the "principal axis" 
>   method is used.

Additionally, for constrained problems the interior point method is used.  If the problem is linear (objective and constraints) linear programming will be used.  (LP itself has, I think, three methods that are used, depending on size and other features.)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I was just using AbsoluteOptions incorrectly, but I guess I just have to hunt through the documentation.

Comment: @Jason `AbsoluteOptions` is meant to work with objects that have options; `Graphics` and `NotebookObject`s come to mind. In a command like the one you suggested, you are effectively passing the output of `FindMinimum` to `AbsoluteOptions`, so I would expect it to work.

Comment: @Brett I happen to be sitting at my computer waiting for an email from Wolfram Research. :)