# Mathematica: AbsoluteOptions not working properly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

According to the documentation `AbsoluteOptions[expr,name]` "gives the absolute setting for the option name".

"`AbsoluteOptions` gives the actual settings for options used internally by Mathematica when the setting given is Automatic or All."

Here is an example they show:

```
<< AbsoluteOptions[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotRange -> Automatic], PlotRange]
>> {PlotRange -> {{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}}
```

Here I use << to denote Input and >> to denote output.

This seems to work fine. However, when I try to obtain the `AspectRatio` of a plot it simply gives me Automatic. Try this,

```
AbsoluteOptions[
 ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic],
  AspectRatio
 ]
```

Similar format as the example they show but the output I get is simply

```
{AspectRatio->Automatic}
```

Does this mean that the argument `expr` can only be a `Graphics` object and not `Graphics3D`? This doesn't make sense because it works fine if I try to obtain the `PlotRange` of a `Graphics3D` object. Is this a bug or my mathematica is broken? Another thing could be that the documentation is not being very specific. Which one is it?
Here is a link to the documentation:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html

I'm using Mathematica 7.0.1.0.

Comment: @jmlopez it gives Automatic for Plot3D too here (mma 8)...

Comment: Must be a bug or documentation problem then.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288713/how-to-determine-plotrange-to-include-all-of-graphics

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to dislike Mathematica now. All I want is to get consistent good looking graphics. Now it turns out I can't really depend on their functions. I might as well write my own routines and make a python script to draw svg pictures.

Comment: @jmlopez perhaps asking another, more specific, question (such as describing in detail the graphics you are trying to create) will attract some useful responses

Comment: @acl, very well. I will post a question later this evening. Maybe someone here already battled with what I'm dealing with.

Comment: @acl here is the question. I decided to forget about this method and simply specify my own aspect ratio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301676/mathematica-rasters-in-3d-graphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `ImageDimensions` directly to `Graphics3D` to get its `ImageSize`.

It seems that `AbsoluteOptions` just was not modified since *Mathematica* 4 (see bottom of the corresponding [documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html)). This function is very buggy (often gives wrong value for `PlotRange` for 2D graphics generated by `Show`, for example) and sometimes does not work at all as you pointed in your question. Compare it with [`FullOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullOptions.html) and [`FullGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullGraphics.html) those are seemed to be not modified since version 2... Sometimes `FullOptions` gives right value when `AbsoluteOptions` gives wrong or does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, BoxRatios is the one you are looking for. HTH.

Comment: No, these are not the droids I'm looking for. I want to know the AspectRatio of the image so that I can give that AspectRatio to another one. I also can't seem to find the ImageSize.

Comment: You could use `Rasterize` to get the bounding box, in pixel dimensions.

Comment: @jmlopez You can apply `ImageDimensions` directly to `Graphics3D` to get its `ImageSize`.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov, Could you write your comment on an answer to the question so that I can give you proper credit? It might also be a good idea to point out what you have found broken as far as options for graphics go.

Comment: @jmlopez It seems that `AbsoluteOptions` just was not modified since *Mathematica* 4. This function is very buggy (often gives wrong value for `PlotRange` for 2D graphics generated by `Show`, for example) and sometimes does not work at all as you pointed in your question. Compare it with `FullOptions` and `FullGraphics` those are seemed to be not modified from version 2... Sometimes `FullOptions` gives right value when `AbsoluteOptions` gives wrong or does not work at all.

Comment: @Alexey, I would like to give proper credit to you since you have answered my question. I'm getting tired of seeing: "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

Comment: @jmlopez I have created answer and copied my comments into it.