# Forcing x axis to align with y axis in Mathematica Plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

In Mathematica, when I plot things sometimes I don't always get the x-axis to line up with the exact bottom of the plot. Is there any way I can force it to do this all the time?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJPkg.png

I want the x-axis to line up perfectly with the zero tick mark way at the bottom, not in the middle of the y-axis as it is in that image.

Any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I think it would help if you could add the mathematica statement that produced that plot/image to your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the option [`AxesOrigin -> {0,0}`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AxesOrigin.html)

Answer (score 5):

The following will draw your Axes on the left and bottom, irrespective to the coordinate values:

```
aPlot[f_, var_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Plot[f, var,
  AxesOrigin -> 
   First /@ (# /. AbsoluteOptions[Plot[f, var, opts], #] &@PlotRange), opts]

aPlot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

```
aPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: @belisarius: I like your solution and Alexey Popkov's derived solution for their generality, but I want to stay away from them simply because it's so much more complicated and the alignment I need to do is easily satisfied by `AxesOrigin->{0, 0}`. It's too bad something like this isn't already built into Mathematica.

Comment: @Mike If all you need is the {0,0} case, obviously `AxesOrigin` is the way to go!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use something like:  `Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}`

(Also I think that fact that it's not choosing `{0,0}` by default means that `y=0` is being brought into range by `PlotRangePadding`.  So that may be another option to keep an eye on.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is (IMO) more elegant method based on belisarius's code which uses the `DisplayFunction` option (see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/ebf947a54ef5e1e1) interesting discussion on this option):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  Function[{plot}, 
   Show[plot, 
    AxesOrigin -> 
     First /@ (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange]), 
    DisplayFunction -> Identity]]]
```

The only drawback of both methods is that [`AbsoluteOptions` does not always give correct value of `PlotRange`](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00144.html). The solution is to use [the `Ticks` hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288713/how-to-determine-plotrange-to-include-all-of-graphics/7281206#7281206) (which gives the complete `PlotRange` with explicit value of `PlotRangePadding` added):

```
completePlotRange[plot_] := 
 Last@Last@
   Reap[Rasterize[
     Show[plot, Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), DisplayFunction -> Identity], 
     ImageResolution -> 1]]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  Function[{plot}, 
   Show[plot, AxesOrigin -> First /@ completePlotRange[plot], 
    DisplayFunction -> Identity]]]
```

It is interesting to note that this code gives exactly the same rendering as simply specifying `Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, Axes -> False`:

```
pl1 = Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
   Filling -> Axis, 
   DisplayFunction -> 
    Function[{plot}, 
     Show[plot, AxesOrigin -> First /@ completePlotRange[plot], 
      DisplayFunction -> Identity]]];
pl2 = Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
   Filling -> Axis, Frame -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   Axes -> False];
Rasterize[pl1] == Rasterize[pl1]

=> True
```

Comment: I knew about the PlotRange anomaly, but I thought it was related to some Plot[] cousins, but not to Plot[] itself.